# Caputuring a Silverlight Bing Map as an image

Tags: c#, silverlight, bing-maps

The WriteableBitmap class that was introduced in Silverlight 3 does not allow images to be rendered from a different domain for security reasons and hence it is impossibe to output an image of the Bing Map.

Does anyone have any suggestions for a workaround? I just want to capture a snapshot of the image including the controls and shapes I have drawn on the overlying canvas

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround - the bing maps silverlight control allows you to specify a custom configuration.  In this configuration, you can specify your own URLs for images, and make them so that they are not cross-domain, and hence not "insecure".

However, there is a bug in Silverlight which causes the workaround to fail.  See here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/628962/

The sample attached to the bug report in the link above shows how to specify a custom map control configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Bing's Imagery Service? See
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966738.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It would be shame if something that is inplace for good security reasons could then be worked around, wouldn't it?

It may be that your true goal might be achievable using some other approach but you don't state what that is.

For example, you might want to generate some simple image that can then be hosted on a web site to be downloaded.  A possible workaround would be to use the Silveright print API to print the desired content.  Use a PDF generating printer driver you could then upload the generated PDF to the site

Of course this example may be far from your purpose.  State your intent and a more lateral work around may be offered or at least a definitive, "no you can't".

Comment: I have an interactive map that overlays levels/prevalences of diseases in a local authority areas. This map along with the accompanying analyses need to be automatically placed into a report document in order for other people to view once the map and analyses have been created.